# Cannot cast desde Objeto a Int al intentar usar como argumento en una función

Tags: java

Tengo una clase `Recuperacolor` que tiene una función `getPrecio`

public class Recuperacolor {

```
  public static int getPrecio(int numcolor) {
      switch(numcolor) {
      case 0:
          return 1;
      case 1:
          return 2;
      case 2:
          return 1;
      case 3:
          return 2;
      default:
          return 0;
      }
  }
```

Desde la clase Vendedor en el main quiero llamar a la función `getPrecio` pasándole como argumento `MiColor`que es un objeto, aunque recoge un int. Así que lo intento convertir a un int haciendo esto:

```
int Color = (int) MiColor;
```

Para así pasarle `Color` a la función `getPrecio`.

Sin embargo no funciona, me da error "Cannot cast from Recuperacolor to int"

```
public class Vendedor {
static Recuperacolor MiColor;
static Recuperafigura MiFigura;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    // Informar al cliente y guardar color seleccionado:
    Recuperacolor.RecuperarColores();

    // Aquí MiColor recoge un int, sin embargo no se convierte a int:
    MiColor = Recuperacolor.PreguntaColor();

    // Intento crear variable int para que coja el valor de MiColor:
    int Color = (int) MiColor;

    int PrecioColor = Recuperacolor.getPrecio(Color); // DA ERROR
}
```

}

Código completo:

```js
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Recuperacolor {
 
 String color;
 int precio;
  static List<Recuperacolor> miscolores = new ArrayList();


 public static void RecuperarColores() throws Exception { 
 String host = "localhost";
    String dbname = "fabrica";
    String port = "3306";
    String url = "jdbc:mariadb://" + host + "/" + dbname;
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    

    String query = "SELECT * FROM colores";
    
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    
    while (rs.next()) {
      String r1 = rs.getString("nombrecolor");
      int r2 = rs.getInt("preciocolor");
      
      miscolores.add(new Recuperacolor(r1, r2));
    }
    
    st.close();
  }
 
   public static void pinta(List<Recuperacolor> arg) { System.out.println("COLORES DISPONIBLES: " + miscolores.size());
     System.out.println();
     
     for (int i = 0; i < miscolores.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(i + " - " + miscolores.get(i));
     }
   }
   
   public static Recuperacolor PreguntaColor() {
     Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     int mic;
     do {
       System.out.println("Numero de color Elegido?");
       mic = teclado.nextInt();
     } while (

       mic >= miscolores.size());
     
     return (Recuperacolor)miscolores.get(mic);
   }
   
   private int elcolor;

   public int getMicolor(){
    return this.elcolor;
   }

   public void setMicolor(int micolor){
    this.elcolor = micolor;
   } 
   
   public static int getPrecio(int numcolor) {
    switch(numcolor) {
    case 0:
     return 1;
    case 1:
     return 2;
    case 2:
     return 1;
    case 3:
     return 2;
    default:
     return 0;
    }
   }
   
   protected String getColor() {
     return color;
   }
   
   protected void setColor(String color) { this.color = color; }
   /*
   protected int getPrecio() {
     return precio;
   }*/
   
   protected Recuperacolor(String color, int precio)
   {
     this.color = color;
     this.precio = precio;
   }
   
   protected void setPrecio(int precio) { this.precio = precio; }
   
   public String toString() {
     return color + " (" + precio + "e/m2)";
   }
 
}
```

```js
package proyecto;

import proyecto.Recuperacolor;
import proyecto.Recuperafigura;

public class Vendedor {
 static Recuperacolor MiColor;
 static Recuperafigura MiFigura;
 static Recuperafigura NumFiguras;
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  // Recuperar datos de la BBDD:
  Recuperacolor.RecuperarColores();
  Recuperafigura.RecuperarFiguras();
  
  // Pregunta usuario por color y asigna precio:
  MiColor = Recuperacolor.PreguntaColor();
  
 
  // Pregunta usuario por figura y asigna precio:
  MiFigura = Recuperafigura.PreguntaFigura();
  
  
  // Pregunta usuario por cantidad de figuras:
  NumFiguras = Recuperafigura.PreguntaCuantasFig();
  //int Cantidad = NumFiguras;
  System.out.println(MiColor, MiFigura, NumFiguras);
  
  // ES LA QUE QUEDA:
  float area;
  
  //double PRECIOFINAL = ((PrecioColor + PrecioFigura) * Area) * Cantidad;

  
 }
 

}
```

Comment: // Aquí MiColor recoge un int, sin embargo no se convierte a int:
    MiColor = Recuperacolor.PreguntaColor(); Creo que debería  hacerlo así : MiColor=(int)Recuperacolor.PreguntaColor(); O Integer.ParseInt ....

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez Me da el mismo error amigo

Comment: Intente con este método creo que le faltan los break en el case

Comment: public static int getPrecio(int numcolor) {
         int resultado=0;
          
        switch(numcolor) {
          case 0:
              resultado =1;
              break;
          case 1:
              resultado =2;
              break;
          case 2:
              resultado =1;
              break;
          case 3:
              resultado =2;
              break;
          default:
              resultado =0;
              break;
             }
             
             return resultado;
      }

Comment: Donde esta el método PreguntaColor();

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez actualizo con todo el código

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo el sentido de tu casteo, si queres un int la clase Recuperacolor deberia tener un atributo del tipo int y con su get corespondiente,

```
public class Recuperacolor(){

     private int micolor;

    public int getMicolor(){
        return this.micolor;
    }

    public void setMicolor(int micolor){
        this.micolor= micolor;
    }
}
```

y en tu método pregunta color setear mi color `setMicolor(1)` para después enviarle a `getPrecio(Recuperacolor.getMicolor());`

Comment: Entiendo, y porque cuando le pongo en el setter la linea "this.micolor = micolor;" me dice "This method must return a result of type int"? Se supone que micolor es int. Lo he declarado igual que tu código :S

Comment: Disculpa escribi mal el codigo los metodos set son del tipo void no deben retornar nada seria public void setMicolor(int micolor){

Comment: Cierto! Perdona te vuelvo a escribir porque sigo sin entender que realmente soluciona lo que me has dicho? Por que si digo "MiColor.setMicolor(micolor);" El argumento del setter necesita un Int y yo solo puedo recoger el objeto entero en el metodo "preguntacolor".  O así querías decir MiColor.setMicolor(Recuperacolor.PreguntaColor()); ? ?

Comment: Te explico, estas declarando una "variable" del tipo Recuperacolor o sea que esa variable tiene los atributos de Recuperarcolor. podrias mostrarme como esta conformada esa clase? en todo caso si la clase solo tiene un metodo getPrecio() no deberias declararla como static podrias instanciarla para pasarle el color como parametro al metodo getPrecio

Comment: Ok, ahora mismo Añado código completo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Intente con este código en el case falta el break

```
 public static int getPrecio(int numcolor) {
         int resultado=0;

        switch(numcolor) {
          case 0:
              resultado =1;
              break;
          case 1:
              resultado =2;
              break;
          case 2:
              resultado =1;
              break;
          case 3:
              resultado =2;
              break;
          default:
              resultado =0;
              break;
             }

             return resultado;
      }
```

Comment: Al tener un return en cada case, el break es innecesario

Comment: Cierto también sirve